# cron.weekly and cron.monthly run times

Tags: script, cron, root

What day of the week does cron.weekly run on

What day of the month does cron.monthly run on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cron.weekly` runs on day 0 of the week (Sunday). `cron.monthly` runs on the first day of the month.

See `/etc/crontab` for more details.